# Search is not working with custom managed property

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, managed-property, crawled-property

I have created a new managed property which maps to a crawled property of Date Field. 
But when I am trying to search with the newly managed property I am not able to get any search result.
My column’s display name is 'Date of Execution' and Internal Name is 'ExecutionDate'but I noticed in crawled properties I find two properties 'ows_DateofExecution' and 'ows_ExecutionDate' I mapped my managed property with both the crawled properties even though search is not working with Managed Properties.
My Managed property is already set as 'searchable' and retrievable.

I also did Site and List Level reIndexing and ran full crawl after but that also didn't work. 
Please suggest if any more troubleshooting step I can try to make this workable?

I am using SharePoint 2013 On-Premises farm.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The crawled property which you should be looking for mapping will look like **ows_q_DATE_DocumentDate** Here 'DocumentDate' is my custom field.

Also, please check what managed property you have mapped to this and use this as the prefix to your Search keyword.

Alternatively, You can Map your crawled property of date to some *RefinableDate00* and give it an alias say "ContosoAlias". then perform a search with a query as - "**ContosoAlias: your_search_keyward"** It will surely work for you.

**Edit**- Steps

1. Go to Site Settings -> Schema (under Search section)
2. Type refinabledate in searchbox to get managed property
3. Select 'RefinableDate00' and click on Edit
4. Provide an Alias name eg. *ContosoAlias*
5. Click Add mapping to look for your respective crawled property and clik OK
6. Go to your Search Box and write a query like ContosoAlias: 6/14/2018

Done !!

PS: You can use the managed property to refine your results as well.